# Tengo un problema con una matriz simétrica en C

Tags: c, condiciones

En esta tarea tengo que crear un programa en C que indique si una matriz determinada de orden 3 es simétrica o no.
La salida debe ser algo así:

INPUT

```
I-COORD?
1
J-COORD?
1
VALUE?
10
I-COORD?
1
J-COORD?
2
VALUE?
2
I-COORD?
1
```

OUTPUT

```
IS SYMMETRIC (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE): 1
```

El problema que me surge con el código es que, al ejecutar el programa, siempre me sale como resultado: 1, aunque la matriz no sea simétrica. Agradecería que alguien me pudiese ayudar.
**PD**: solo puedo usar estructuras de control alternativas (condicionales), no puedo usar bucles para simplificarlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define rows 3
#define columns 3

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    
    /*Variable definition*/
    int m[rows][columns];
    int i,j,x,y,v;
    i=x-1;
    j=y-1;
    
    printf("INPUT\n");
    
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    printf("I-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("J-COORD?\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("VALUE?\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    m[i][j]= v;
    
    printf("OUTPUT\n");
    printf("IS SYMMETRIC (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE):");
    if ((m[0][1]==m[1][0])&&(m[2][0]==m[0][2])&&(m[2][1]==m[1][2])){
        printf("1");
    } else{
        printf("0");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cuando seteas tu matriz siempre lo haces en el mismo casillero, tienes que cambiar `m[i][j]= v` por algo como  `m[x-1][y-1]= v`

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado el código creando 1 variable de "i" y "j" para cada posición y he sustituido m[i][j]=v por m[x-1][y-1]=v. Ahora creo que ya funciona. Gracias!

#include <stdio.h>

#define rows 3
#define columns 3

int main(int argc, char **argv){

```
/*Variable definition*/
int m[rows][columns];
int i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9;
int j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,j6,j7,j8,j9;
int v;

printf("INPUT\n");

printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i1);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j1);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i1-1][j1-1]= v;
printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i2);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j2);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i2-1][j2-1]= v;
printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i3);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j3);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i3-1][j3-1]= v;

printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i4);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j4);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i4-1][j4-1]= v;
printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i5);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j5);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i5-1][j5-1]= v;
printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i6);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j6);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i6-1][j6-1]= v;

printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i7);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j7);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i7-1][j7-1]= v;
printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i8);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j8);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i8-1][j8-1]= v;
printf("I-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&i9);
printf("J-COORD?\n");
scanf("%d",&j9);
printf("VALUE?\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
m[i9-1][j9-1]= v;

printf("OUTPUT\n");
printf("IS SYMMETRIC (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE):");
if ((m[0][1]==m[1][0])&&(m[2][0]==m[0][2])&&(m[2][1]==m[1][2])){
    printf("1");
} else{
    printf("0");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Si sos el mismo usuario de la pregunta, solicitá [fusionar tus cuentas](/contact), en _Problema de Cuenta_ > _Necesito combinar perfiles de usuario_.